# opendaylight: How can I get all the source code that was included in the neon release?

Tags: opendaylight

I want to get all the source code corresponding to the Neon release from github. How can I get this? Are the releases tagged in some standardized way?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each project's repo will be tagged every release. For example, you can
`git checkout refs/tags/release/oxygen-sr2` to get the bits that were released
for the 2nd Service Release of Oxygen.